# Create light animation using either xaml or C#

Tags: c#, xaml, animation

I would like to animate text highlight like "slide to unlock" iPhone.
Could you please help me?
Thanks!

[image: iPhone slide]

Comment: Use a Gradient. I have no experience with iPhones. Is it that the more you slide, the greater the part of the text becomes white(er)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use a **LinearGradientBrush** and then animate its gradient stops to create a "strobing" effect.

The following is the XAML for a basic **Window** with some text that illustrates the technique:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Background="Black">
    <TextBlock x:Name="_text" Text="Hello World"
        FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0"
                ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation">
                <GradientStop Color="#ff666666" Offset="-0.2" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ffffffff" Offset="-0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ff666666" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="_text"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                            From="-0.2" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="_text"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                            From="-0.1" To="1.6" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="_text"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                            From="0" To="1.7" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

You can experiment with the **GradientStop** colours and offsets, plus the duration of the **DoubleAnimation** elements, to get the effect you're after. Just remember that the durations for all three animation elements must be the same.

---

To use in WPF instead of Universal Windows, the **EventTrigger** needs to have its **RoutedEvent** property set, and the **EnableDependentAnimation** property of the **Storyboard** must be removed. Something like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
    <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
             ...
         </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! It worked perfectly on WPF! However, when I tried to use it on Universal Windows, it doesn't work. Note that I had to change RoutedEvent from "Loaded" to "TextBlock.Loaded" and still doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks...

Comment: Based on the example from this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.eventtrigger.aspx), it looks as though the `RoutedEvent` attribute is not supported in Windows Universal apps. I've edited the code sample in my answer. Maybe give that a go and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I've also changed the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` paths slightly based on another [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187354) that I read. Unfortunately I cannot test these code changes as I have no means of writing Windows Universal apps at this time.

Comment: You may also need to set the `EnableDependentAnimation` property, according to that same MSDN page. I presume this goes on the `Storyboard` element (the page wasn't clear on that point).

Comment: Yes, EnableDependentAnimation worked! Apparently, it is something like <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="_text" EnableDependentAnimation="True">. Thanks Steven!

Comment: Does this work on WPF ? Now I'm trying on WPF but argumentnullexception is occuring with RoutedEvent and seems EnableDependentAnimation is for Universal Windows. Can you kindly guide me to WPF's solution ?

Comment: @KayLee Yes, for WPF you need to set the `RoutedEvent` and remove `EnableDependentAnimation`. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @StevenRands, oh, the edited solution works in WPF beautifully. Many thanks for your kindness :)